# Can i remove some place name which is suggested by Place API?

Tags: android, google-places-api

For e.g. when i select cafe option it give all coffee cafe name and cyber cafe name. I want to remove a cyber cafe name.

I am new to android development.

Comment: Can you show us your code? This way it's easier for us to give a more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by remove?

You can filter the places returned by the google places API and display only those which you want the user to see in listView.